# SVAR and Impulse Response function

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

i cannot figure the difference between a VAR (vector autoregressive) and the Structural VAR (SVAR).
Beside the math, I would like to have a simple explanation of how the SVAR differs from the VAR.

Moreover, I also don't understand what is the magnitude of the shock in the impulse response function. I mean, when I run the impulse response function in R, it gives as result several plots which show the response of one variable given a shock on another variable.
The question is, what shock does R accounts for? Is it a 1% shock or calculated in some other way? Is there a way to input in the irf an arbitrary shock? (say 5%)

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me out with this.

Thanks